# Copy table from one data connection and paste into database in another data connection in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, auto-increment, alphanumeric

This may be super obvious, but I can't see it. I have a table I created in SQL Server Management Studio. I had to create it there because I needed to use a function for an alpha-numeric ID column that increments itself. I then exported the table, but had to use my local server. Now, in visual studio, I have the local server connection that contains the table I want to copy to a connection for a remote server. I can right-click and select 'Copy', but I can't right-click and 'Paste' into the database I need.

I'm fairly new at this and if anyone has a better way to make an auto incrementing alpha-numeric column in Visual Studio, I would love to hear about it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you created the table in the other database?

Answer (score 0):

I would go back into SQL Server Management Studio, connect to the remote server, and create the table there. This would also show you any possible permissions issues that you may have on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update your app.config file in your VB Project.
You can right click on the project and click properties
Under 'Settings' you will find a 'Connection' with a 'Name' and a 'Value'
You need to change the value for 'Connection Properties' for:
Server Name:  from LOCALHOST to your remote server url
Also be sure to update username/password credentials
Click 'Test Connection' to confirm you can connect

You can also manually edit these settings in the app.config file
You can also manually edit the MyApp.exe.config file where your app is deployed (where MyApp is the executable name)